# Learning path for soloing and improvisation

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, improvisation, solos

I'm still not sure what it's called , I thought it may be these two I mentioned in the title.

What I want to learn is being able to follow with the lead guitar and do the licks just like in an indie band, the lead is playing some chords and the other guitar is doing some follow up solos or improvisation . 
I hope I can find my answer and know what are the prerequisites to be able to learn all of that and be able to reach that level.

Comment: http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/16307/guitar-solo-techniques?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

There are already plenty of similar questions here with great answers. Things like - know some scales, in the keys you play in, be able to change what you play according to the chords played, *LISTENING TO THE OTHERS!*, etc. Look on the right of screen for lots of good tips.